# ASP.NET MVC2: How to redirect to GET Details/5 after POST Add

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am absolute beginner in C#, ASP.NET and MVC2 and this means that I just might be missing something exceptionally basic. I tried to search for it, but here again, I failed to come up with the proper incantations for neither Google not StackOverflow, so here comes the question:

I am trying to create a basic controller with two actions:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Create(CustomerCreateData data)
{
    CustomerRecord cr = //create customer record from input data...

    return RedirectToAction("Details");
}

public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    CustomerRecord cr = // load customer record with specified id...
    return View(cr);
}
```

My idea is thet after successful `POST /Customer/Create` the user would be redirected to `GET /Customer/Details/42` where 42 is id of the newly created customer record.

What is the proper incantation for this in ASP.NET MVC2

PS - I've seen countless examples of redirecting to `"Index"` action, but that is not quite enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass data to the `RedirectToAction` method:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = cr.Id });
```

This is assuming you either have a defined route, e.g. `Customer/Details/{id}` or that you still have the default route `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

Answer (score 1):

In Create ActionResult, after creation success make an action like this (or realy this for example):

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { Id = cr.Id });
```

This code produce a redirect to Details/id/{cr.Id}.
Sorry for bad english (i'm italian)